# Comparison between Vishnu and Shiva?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, brahma, shakti

Comparison between Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva by each parts, qualities, astras etc.

Comment: Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva both are of infinite qualities and infinite attributes... They can not be compared... They are beyond comparison.. They are same in two different forms... **"Eka eva dwidha bhuto loke charati nityesa"**.. ie.. The same Lord is always moving in World in two different forms...

Comment: There's no use in comparing. Both are one and same. As said by @Tezz, wise men call the truth by different names.

Comment: @all--I think you need to go deeper into Hinduism--nit just copy paste from the website.  Your pwn wordings are not there.

Answer (score 3):

Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva both are of infinite qualities and infinite attributes. They are the same Lord moving in two different forms.

Lord Krishna in **Vishnu Purana** in the **Banasura fight chapter** states:

> **अविद्यामोहितात्मान** पुरुषा भिन्न दर्शिन । 
>   वदन्ति भेद पश्यन्ति चावयोरन्तर हरः ।। 
>  
>   Person whose Atman is deluded by Avidya sees difference between me and Hara (Shiva). He alone sees and talks difference between me and Hara.

In the above verse Lord Krishna uses the term **"AvidyaMohitatmana"** ie. Whose Atman is deluded by Avidya/Ignorance.
Similarly Harivamsha Parva of Mahabharata in Banasura fight chapter states:

> **एक एव द्विध भूतो लोके चरति नित्यस** ।।
>   The same Lord is always moving in World in two different forms (ie. Shiva and Vishnu)

So, as they are same, quality of one Lord definitely belongs to another Lord. Similarly their wearing, astra and clothes belong to each other as they are same. However this relation is hard to conceive for people as they are deluded by ignorance. Even Lord Brahma sees this relation in dream, [Harivamsha Parva Mahabharata Banasura fight episode (2.125 section)]:

> हरं च हरिरुपेण हरिं च हररुपिणम् ।
>   **शङ्खचक्रगदापाणि पीताम्बरधरं हरम्**।।
>  
>   Hara was on the form of Hari and Hari was on the form of Hara. **Hara** was wearing yellow clothes and **in his hands were Sankha, Chakra and Gada.**
>   
>   **त्रिशुलपट्टिशधरं व्याघ्रचर्मधरं हरिम्** ।
>   गरुडस्थ चापि हरं हरिं च वृषभध्वजम् ।।
>  
>   **Hari** was wearing tiger skin and **holding a Trishula.** Hara was riding on Garuda and Hari was riding on bull.

And in the same chapter, when Brahma tells the above fact, then Markandaye states:

> शिवाय विष्णु रुपाय विष्णवे शिवरुपिने । 
>   यथान्तरं न पश्यमि तेन तौ दिष्ट: शिवम् ।।
>
> **Shiva is in the form of Vishnu and Vishnu is in the form of Shiva. There is no difference between them and both provide Auspiciousness.**

Comment: are there any diffrence between Parbrahman and Brahman or not?

Comment: There is no difference in Brahman and ParaBrahman... both Brahman and ParaBrahman are infinite... and infinite can't be compared... Brahman and ParaBrahman are frequently used as exchangable term in our scriptures...

Comment: parātparaṭaro Brahma tat parātparaṭo hari tat paratparatparatarod ishas ṭanmē manaḥ śivasaṇkalpamasṭu... Rigveda makes it very clear. For Harmony amidst the Hindus of modern day, one can implement the oneness as Vaishnavas are becoming more in number since 1000 years, but reality can never be denied, secularism is fine for some aspects of the betterment of society, just like we sometimes say Allah and Ishvar both are same. But doesn't change the reality of Allah being imaginary and Ishvara being the eternal supreme.

Answer (score -1):

1. Lord Vishnu is quite whereas Lord Shiva gets angry easily.
2. Lord Vishnu offer boon with thorough care whereas Lord Shiva will grant boon if he was praised. This is applicable to Lord Brahma also.
   Example--Ravana got the boons from Lord Shiva and once he went to kailash and tried to shake it. At last he was killed by Lord Vishnu.
3. Lord Vishnu's main weapons are shanku and chakra whereas Lord Shiva's weapon is trident.[soolam]
   4.Albeit Lord Vishnu is described as preserver and Lord Shiva as destroyer in charanagathi Tatwa it is mentioned as Lord Vishnu is one and all. Creator, preserver and destroyer.
4. Lord Vishnu is sky blue in colour [Yoga sleep in milky ocean] and Lord Shiva is dark blue from neck to feet because he drank the poison from the churn of Amirtham.

Vishnu puranam, Shiva puranam, Bagavatham, Kodayin Paadhai are the books from where the citings can be seen.

Comment: I think your few points are wrong here...:1) Lord Shiva gets angry easily as his one name is Rudra... but he gets pleased easily too.. He is Bholenath... also he is Shiva which means auspicious..there is auspiciousness alone in his anger also 2) Lord Shiva is omniscient, he is fully aware of consequences of his boons.. still he gives... because he is fully aware of it... he is beyond time 3)Lord Vishnu is not sky blue... he is dark blue like rain cloud **(meghavarnam)**.. also only neck of Lord Shiva is blue...he is white in complexion.. **karpura gauram**.. ie . As white as camphor...

Comment: @Tezz  some explanations

Comment: @Tezz  some explanations  1, Lord Shiva plucked Lord Brahma's one head  at one incident and for many years that head was fixed in his hand. This is Brahma hathi dosham . It got solved after he had a bhiksha from Goddess Mahalakshmi at Uttamar koil. [Trichy].  2. Lord Shiva and Lord Brahma  gave boon to Hiranyakasipu and cannot withstands before him. At last Lord Vishnu took Narasimha Avatar and killed Hiranyakasipu. . As per vaishnava traditions Lord Narayana is omnipresent  Kindly read Varaha puranam and Sri Baghavatham..

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Well, i can also cite you Puranas where Lord Shiva is mentioned as Omnipresent and where Lord Vishnu took help of Shiva. This is age-old debate and there's no conclusion for this issue. Only possible resolution for this is, **ADVAITA**.

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan 1) I had read it's Bhairava manifestation of Shiva who cut Brahmas head and his hand gets stuck. Finally he emerges after dipping hand in Ganga. That place is called Kapala Mochana now. 2) I'm not aware of Lord Shiva giving boon to Hiranyakashipu. BUT ANYWAY killing of Hiranyakashipu by Vishnu was predestined.. Read the story of Jaya and Vijaya in Vaikuntha... 3) and not per only Vaishnava tradition, in common Hinduism also.. Lord Narayana is omnipresent and merciful....

Comment: @ The destroyer---Because you follow saivism and I follow vaishnavism there is no conclusion as said by you-----Time will show us the omnipresent.

Comment: @Tezz---You mentioned about Kapala Mocha and I came to know about Uttamar koil wherein at both Lord Shiva is affected by Brahma Hathi dosham.